# Modifying an ArrayList that's being shared accross files

Tags: java, websocket, collision-detection, concurrentmodification

**Background:**

I'm making a game that uses websockets to interact with the client, and Threads to run the main game loop (inside a Game class). To restrict the amount of times the Websocket Endpoint sends a game-update message (to about 60fps), I also use a TimerTask in the Websocket Endpoint.

**The problem:**

When dealing with collision detection between objects, things started to go wrong. I get an error when converting the modified game-elements collection to JSON (I use `gson` for this) to send it to the client (illustrated as *`things`* in the below code, it's an `ArrayList` with objects inside).

The error is an `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. After some research, I figured out you can't use a simple `for` loop with `break` when removing items on the current index. So I tried out the some of the commonly suggested fixes, and I stuck with the most popular one, by using an Iterator:

**First solution:**

```
private void collisionDetectionHandler() {

    for (Iterator<Thing> iterator = things.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Thing thing = iterator.next();
        boolean colliding = collisionDetection(player, things);
        if(colliding){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This, however, did not fix it completely. Yes, it made it run smoother, but I still get the same error every once in a while.

I think I've figured out why but I don't have a decent idea how to fix it: (I think) sometimes the method is still deleting elements from the list, while at the same time the Websocket is converting that same list to JSON to send it to the client.

I've found a few weak workarounds but nothing really good:
what works is making the above method in my Game class public and calling it inside the Websocket Endpoint before I send the game updates, but that completely splits the game logic because all the other updates are handled inside the Thread in the Game class...

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: ConcurrentModificationException says that it can be that different threads are trying to change the same collection at the same time, or that you're trying to alter the collection while looping over it. Why are you removing the iterator when colliding? I think you should copy your array and change the copy instead of the original.

Comment: Thanks! As you suggested, copying the collection, altering the copy and then pointing the original to the new one seems to do the trick. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: FWIW, invoking `remove()` via the iterator explicitly **is** allowed.  What's not allowed is doing so whilst **concurrently** iterating in a different thread (or generally while having another iterator to the same list).